# Make cookie last forever?

Tags: php, android

So I use WebView in my android-app and would like to make a cookie that lasts forever or something likely. Right now so after a while when you open up the app again, you are logged out. I want to do so you always are logged in no matter what. I don't know if I should in my PHP-code write something or if I somehow should get the app to store something or such.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I use $_SESSION that I want to last longer.

Comment: I fear the sun will burn us all sometimes... including your cookie ;)

Answer (score 3):

There's no possibility to set cookie last forever, this is defined by the cookie specification, not PHP itself. But you can set cookie to very far future date, for eg:

```
setcookie(
  'name'
  'value',
   time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 20) // 20 years 
);
```

Be careful: if you set a date past year 2038 in PHP, the number will wrap around and you'll get a cookie that expires instantly (it will reset seconds counting back to 0 from 1 jan 1970)

Comment: I want to add, that the user can at every time delete the cookies. So don't expect that there is this cookie!

Comment: Just realised I missed out on mentioning. To get the users id I use $_SESSION['sess_id'], is it possible to change the length for how long a $_SESSION is available?

Comment: @user2065518 session is cookie-based, so there's same problem here, if cookie will expire or will be deleted by user your session will also expire.